# Configure Notepad++ to use indentation-based code folding

Tags: notepad++, folding

It's not that it can't handle it. It does it for Python.

How can I ask it to do the same with other languages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is hardcoded into Scintilla's lexers for Python and other languages respectively (Scintilla is the editing component that Notepad++ uses), so you can't change this with some configuration setting.

The relevant documentation I found for folding mostly points to writing lexers for Scintilla. See the [home page](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html) for some links.